# Using the power query GUI to nest tables

Tags: powerquery

powerquery: This follow-up question relates to;

[Aggregation/Summation of text and numeric fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68964457/aggregation-summation-of-text-and-numeric-fields)

Ron, could you please clarify, from your “group by” code statements what is the equivalent if completing in the GUI.

I can get close but not the same as yours, or is it not possible to nest tables in the GUI ?

The "group by" portion of your code delivers this,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHz1B.png

I would like to achieve the same via the GUI

Below is what I am ultimately trying to achieve using code as the GUI did not work out as planned.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/23naf.png

I have tried "table.group" nesting as follows

---

Site

------->Agency

-------------->Division

---

Site

------->Agency

------->Division

---

Site

------->Agency

Site

------->Division

---

But not quite exactly what I want. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could do an initial grouping with no aggregation, and then add the subgrouping in an Add Custom Column dialog box with a similar formula. If your goal is to not use the Advanced Editor, you could explore that possibility.  I don't see any advantage to that method, and it would result in more complex, and possibly less efficient code.

Comment: Aggregation looks mandatory in the GUI

Comment: You didn't look far enough at the options.  There is an option for "all"

Comment: I think you meant there is an option for "all rows". Anyway I have updated my post with what I am trying to achieve. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please **edit your question** to show the formula you are using in your Custom Column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't understand your reluctance to use the Advanced Editor, but here is a method of adding a bunch of custom columns, each with their own custom formula, to get the results you show.

- Paste in the M code and change the Source as per the previous instructions.
- Then you can double click on any of the added custom columns in the Applied Steps to see the custom formula that was used.

  - I renamed the steps so they would be easier to follow.
  - Any step with a 'gear' icon on the right can be opened to examine the associated dialog box.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table15"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"SiteName", type text}, {"Agency", type text}, {"Division", type text}, {"Staff Numbers", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"SiteName"}, 
        {{"ALL", each _, type table [SiteName=nullable text, Agency=nullable text, Division=nullable text, Staff Numbers=nullable number]}}),
    
    Agency = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Agency", each Text.Combine(List.Distinct([ALL][Agency]),"/")),
    
    #"Agency Staff Numbers Tbl" = Table.AddColumn(Agency, "Agency Staff Numbers tbl", each 
        Table.Group([ALL],"Agency", {"Agency Staff Numbers",each List.Sum([Staff Numbers])})),
    #"Agency Staff Numbers" = Table.AddColumn(#"Agency Staff Numbers Tbl", "Agency Staff Numbers", 
        each Text.Combine(List.Transform([Agency Staff Numbers tbl][Agency Staff Numbers],each Text.From(_)),"/")),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Agency Staff Numbers",{"Agency Staff Numbers tbl"}),

    Division = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Division", each Text.Combine(List.Distinct([ALL][Division]),"/")),
    
    #"Division Staff Tbl" = Table.AddColumn(Division, "Divison Staff Numbers Tbl", each 
        Table.Group([ALL],"Division", {"Division Staff Numbers",(t)=> List.Sum(t[Staff Numbers])})),
    #"Division Staff Numbers" = Table.AddColumn(#"Division Staff Tbl", "Division Staff Numbers", each 
        Text.Combine(List.Transform([Divison Staff Numbers Tbl][Division Staff Numbers],each Text.From(_)),"/")),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Division Staff Numbers",{"Divison Staff Numbers Tbl", "ALL"}),

    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns1",{
        {"Agency", type text}, {"Agency Staff Numbers", type text}, {"Division", type text}, {"Division Staff Numbers", type text}
        })
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

I also added another site for debugging purposes:

[image]